# SQL DATE syntax or usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

i have a problem with the date syntax and i get this error:
'Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date'
I have tried inserting this values in the table like this: '19990531' , '1999-05-31' , 1999-05-31 , 31-05-1999.
So I can not see other ways to do this. Can someone help!

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE [Customer] (
Cus_id integer NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
Adress_id integer NOT NULL,
First_name text NOT NULL,
Last_name text NOT NULL,
Birthdate date NOT NULL,
Phone integer NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Email binary NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Password binary NOT NULL,
signup_time timestamp NOT NULL
```

Comment: `text` has been deprecated for nearly 20 years, and certainly you don't need 2 billion characters in a first or last name. `binary` with no length? Do you want `binary(1)`? Doesn't seem adequate for either an e-mail or a password. `timestamp` does not contain date or time, so maybe you meant `datetime2(0)`?

Comment: You should always use unambiguous, non-regional, language-neutral formats, like `yyyyMMdd`. `'19990531'` works fine for me ([db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9e7f685f8207c3a61893ef1607e9bed4)) ... so, maybe the error is because you're trying to insert the date into the wrong column, or you have a trigger that is trying to do the wrong thing(s) to it.

Comment: In addition to the data type problems @AaronBertrand highlighted , `integer` is also the wrong data type for a phone number. Though called a "number" it includes other characters other than digits (`+` for international dialing codes, `()` are often used for extensions, etc. A value like `+44 1234 567890 (123)` could likely be a very valid entry). Many phone numbers also start with a `0` too, which would be lost with a numerical data type. A `varchar` column, which has a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` to ensure it doesn't have unwanted characters is a *far* better choice.

Comment: Please add all of your code, especially the INSERT part.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71501607/edit) your question to include full insert statements.

Comment: For one of your examples: `1999-05-31` is an expression that resolves to the integer value `1963`... which is not a date value.

Comment: Aside... `signup_time timestamp NOT NULL` isn't what you probably think it is. `timestamp` is a deprecated synonym for [`rowversion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql), a data type which has nothing to do with the `date`, `datetime`, nor `time` data types.